# How do I get autotools to compile with the Intel compiler?

Tags: autotools, autoconf, automake

I want my code to compile with the Intel compiler(s) or with gcc/g++ depending on a configure argument.  Is this possible?  What do I need to put in my configure.ac and Makefile.am files to make this happen?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to use a compiler other than gcc when you compile, pass 'CC=/path/to/compiler' as an argument to configure.  (That is, run ./configure CC=/path.  Do not use the form CC=/path ./configure.)  If you want the default compiler to be something other than gcc, you can put

```
CC=${CC-/path/to/default/compiler}
```

in configure.ac before the invocation of AC_PROG_CC.

Comment: This is not a good approach. Use AC_PROG_CC as advised by freedrull instead.

Answer (score 16):

I would do this:

```
AC_PROG_CC([icc gcc])
```

This will look for the compilers in the order specified, unless overridden with an argument to ./configure

```
$ ./confgure CC=gcc
```

Answer (score 4):

Of course it is. You can configure a default compiler in configure.ac and if the user wants to use another compiler, he (or she) can pass it to the `./configure` script.

You'll find more about it here: [How to use autotools](http://koehllab.genomecenter.ucdavis.edu/documentation/how-to/how-to-use-autotools).

The part that might be interesting for you is at the middle of the page:

```
#if a compiler is not specified by the user use intel compilers
AC_PATH_PROG(CC_PATH, $CC, NO_PATH)
if test "$CC_PATH" = NO_PATH; then
 CC="icc"
fi
```

Comment: Can't you just do this as well:

Comment: Under `autoconf` 2.69, what you suggested results in `The usual way to define 'CC' is to add 'AC_PROG_CC'` for me.

Answer (score 2):

Usually you can just run

```
bash $ CC=icc ./configure
```

to use lcc, or any other compiler as the C compiler, provided the rest of the configure and build process doesn't use any gcc'ism.

Comment: It is better to use: $ ./configure CC=icc.  If you pass CC as an argument to configure then re-configuring with config-status will work. If you set CC in the environment, then it will not.