# ./configure make make install on Windows with icc

Tags: c++, cygwin, compilation, intel

I recently switched back to Windows7 (x64) because of perfomance issues with my graphics card on linux but i miss the abilty to easily compile open source software on Windows. I have a copy of the intel c compiler which is somewhat better than the gnu c compiler and i would like to use it to compile software written for linux.
I've already installed cygwin and managed to compile something. The 'make-install' didn't work though but that's another issue. Now my question is, how can i tell 'make' to use the windows intel compiler?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the `configure` scripts you'll find in OSS have probably been created by the Autotools. Those should, basically, support the icc. To use it, although you may have GCC installed side-by-side, it would be necessary to set the environment variable `CC` to the (cygwin) path to Intel's C compiler and `CXX` to Intel's C++ compiler prior to running `configure`.

You may run into trouble with software packages that unconditionally set compiler flags that  only GCC understands. I have heard, though, that, by now, icc actually implements most of these.

### Update

Something similar has been asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1280418/how-do-i-get-autotools-to-compile-with-the-intel-compiler).

Comment: Thanks for the fast answere! Okay i typed export CC=/path/to/icl.exe and export CXX=/path/to/icl.exe. Didn't work because of what turned out to be whitespace in the path. :) Nothing worked. Not "/Path name" nor "/Path\ name" so i added the path to my path in windows (not in cygwin) and just typed export CC="icl". This worked and the compiler was called but now it gave me following error: "link: unknown option -- o" (yes with the whitespace between -- and o) Any ideas?

Comment: In the link above they set `CC` to `icc`. Is that, by chance, the correct executable?

Comment: there is no such executable in my intel compiler path.. I tried to compile a helloworld.c (using "icl helloworld.c"), but i get the error: catastrophic error: could not open source file "stdio". This is a bit weird.. I looked it up and found several stdio.h on my system and i also tried adding their paths to the windows path variable, but still no luck..

Comment: Compilers typically need to be told about include paths via command line, like so `-I'/path/to/dir1' -I'/path/to/dir2'`. I'm not familiar enough with Cygwin to be sure whether you have to give your Cygwin path or the Windows (`C:\\...`) paths here. Once you figured that out, you may hardcode that into `CC` like `export CC="icl -I'/path/to/dir1' -I'/path/to/dir2'"`. Some compilers want to have a space after `-I`.

Comment: That's the problem. ICC want's Windows Paths, cygwin gives it cygwin-ized paths.  Intel CC won't work under cygwin on Windows without much trickery - see 'cygpath'.

Comment: Hmm i tried with, and without space.. The -I option doesn't fix the error. I tried both, in cygwin and cmd with dos and unix paths.

Comment: Ahh.. jmanning2k you're probably right.. :( That sucks. i probably can't just pipe all paths given to icl through cygpath (easily), can i?