# Using different version of gcc in my project using automake

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, gnu-make, automake

I am using automake for my project. I have gcc 4.2 installed and there is a soft link to gcc-4.2 as gcc. I also installed gcc 4.8 at some other location and now I want my project to use gcc 4.8 from this location. I do not want to change the existing soft link to gcc. So is there any way to do that in configure.ac file.

Comment: Please don't use the `c++` tag unless it's code related. Since this is compiler-related I replaced `c++` with `gcc`.

Comment: This answer to a previous question seems relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1281792/644939

Answer (score 1):

Normally this is not something you do in configure.  configure is about portability, and your problem is different: customizing a build to your particular machine.

Instead the problem is typically solved when running configure:

```
./configure CC=/path/to/other/gcc
```